# fatal error: string: No such file or directory - Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

So I just import an Android project on eclipse to an Android Studio one with ndk C++ to build, and when I try to build I've got an error : (On win7 64x java jdk1.8.0_40 and ndk 10)

> AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"In file included from C:\Users\Myname\AndroidStudioProjects\Myproject\app\src\main\jni\path\to\my\file1.h
>
> [...]
>
> AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"C:\Users\Myname\AndroidStudioProjects\Myproject\app\src\main\jni\path\to\my\file2.h:28:18: fatal error: string: No such file or directory"

In my file1.h I've got an

> #include "path/to/my/filexxx.h"
>
> #include "path/to/my/file2.h"
>
> [...]

I double check, my included path to file2.h is good, there is no error for my others includes like filexxx.h.

Before that I just add the ndk path to my local.properties :

> ndk.dir=C:\Users\path\to\android-ndk-r10d

My Application.mk is like that :

> APP_STL :=stlport_static
>
> APP_ABI:= armeabi-v7a
>
> APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions

And my Android.mk

> LOCAL_PATH:=$(call my-dir)
>
> include $(CLEAR_VARS)
>
> all my files .cpp
>
> [...]
>
> include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Am I missing something to do on android studio to make it works ? Help needed, thanks.

Comment: In `file2.h` do you have `#include <string>`?

Comment: No I didn't have it, I just add it but no change in the build and the error displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the solution, I will explain it here, that can be useful. I followed this tutorial : http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/android/astudio/

And I noticed that it said that the JNI folder must be under the app folder. Mine was automaticaly placed by android studio conversion under the src folder !

Answer (score 3):

Try to add **stl "stlport_static"** to your ndk section in the model build.gradle as following:

```
    ndk {
            moduleName "MyModel"
            stl "stlport_static"
    }
```

If you use Gradle 2.5, it should look like this:

```
    android.ndk {
            moduleName = "MyModel"
            stl = "stlport_static"
     }
```

Comment: Why **stlport_static** and not **stlport_shared**?